# Working around Gmail mailing-list "feature."

Tags: email, google, gmail, mailing-list, application

We're using Google Apps for our domain's e-mail via IMAP.  Whenever mail is sent to a mailing list, copies of the original mail are not received in inboxes.  According to [Google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6588), this is a "feature."

Is there a way to disable this "feature" so that all mail sent to mailing lists appears in inboxes just like all other e-mail?

Perhaps something along the lines of [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/11/24/how-to-disable-and-deactivate-spam-filter-protection-in-gmail-or-google-mail/) method for disabling Google's spam filter??

Comment: I would be interested in this as well, the behaviour is disconcerting from my perspective.

Comment: I wasted a lot of time troubleshooting my mailing list because I wasn't seeing any messages at the Gmail account I was testing from before I figured this out.  Extremely annoying "feature"  My messages weren't going into spam, but I know they were being delivered and accepted by Google mail servers.  Look forward to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do this.  Made my life much easier after I figured this out.

You need to create a filter looking for all email sent from you, to a list of all groups and separated by pipes (the OR symbol) and then "Never send it to Spam"

This causes email you send to a group to appear in your inbox.

from:(you@example.com) 
to:(group1@example.com|group2@example.com|group3@example.com|group4@example.com)
Do this: Never send it to Spam